# File Inside Python Module Not Included (Django, Py2 to Py3 Conversion)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-module, python-2to3

I am migrating a Django project from 2 to 3 and am running into an import(?) error.

One of the apps/modules contains an `__init__.py`, `admin.py`, `forms.py`, `models.py`, `urls.py`, and `view.py`, but when the module is imported/created only `admin`, `forms`, and `models` are a part of it.

A dir of the module looks like this:

```
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'admin',
 'forms',
 'models']
```

If I try something like `import app.views`or `from . import views`, I get a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Can you add the traceback from your SyntaxError to the question? Is this error coming when you use Python2?

Comment: I'm literally only seeing `*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when I start the dev server.

Comment: This is Python 3.8.10.

Comment: Sounds like the error might be in your views.py if it occurs whenever it's imported. Might be worth giving it a look

Answer (score 0):

Those files have been imported in some other part of your code, they are added to the module when imported. When Django starts up it will load several modules automatically, things like your models to populate a registry/cache of all models in your apps

```
>>> import app
>>> dir(app)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'admin', 'apps', 'models']
>>> import app.views
>>> dir(app)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'admin', 'apps', 'models', 'views']
```